# A polynomial with solvable Galois group and solution by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ has a solvable Galois group, then we know that it can be solved in terms of radicals. But do we know how to explicitly write the solutions of $f(x)$ in terms of radicals?

Comment: Do you want to restrict the question to irreducible polynomials?

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely the subject of the thesis (in German)

Distler, "Ein Algorithmus zum Lösen einer Polynomgleichung durch Radikale", [link](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/distler/Diplom.pdf)

The main tool are Lagrange resolvents. For a nice explicit example see section 7.3.